# Can you auto reject phone numbers natively with a Droid phone?

Tags: motorola-droid-x

I have a Droid X and I'm trying to set up an auto reject list and it looks like I have to download a third party app to do it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the features that come with your Droid X, as they may be slightly different than other brands of Android phones.

On my phone (Cyanogenmod 7.1 Gingerbread) there is a setting under `Menu -> Settings -> Call Settings -> Blacklist`, and [another forum user](http://androidforums.com/sprint-hero-support-troubleshooting/23565-how-block-number.html#post1459201) says in Android 2.1 there is an option under `Menu -> settings -> call settings -> all calls -> auto reject`.

[Others](http://androidforums.com/sprint-hero-support-troubleshooting/23565-how-block-number.html#post2987625) say in some contacts applications you can long-press a contact and choose to block them specifically.

Another good solution is to use [Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&hl=en) to handle calls and voicemail and such. It's not built in to begin with, but it's a Google service, so like second party.

Although,

> In ICS you can specify a reject list that matches certain criteria
>   (Start with, Ends with, Includes, Exactly the same as). This way you
>   could specify Start with 1-800 and it would reject all calls that
>   start with 1-800.

according to a post on [this forum](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-x/564364-call-rejection-auto-reject-list.html). So if you're using an ICS ROM, you may be in luck, as most here are [skeptical](https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/696761) about the Droid X getting an official ICS update.

Comment: FYI, on my phone (CM7.2), you can long press the end call button and block them that way. I figured this out after having inadvertently blocked someone for a month. >_< Too easy to do by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Number. Options to block calls and/or texts. Gives you options of sending straight to VM or disconnecting. Very good at recognizing and blocking spam. I also set mine to divert unknown #s to VM. Figured if they wanted to talk bad enough, they wouldnt have their # blocked, lol. 
I realize this isnt native as you were asking, but much better than any native way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Would you mind to share a link with us?